# Installing PL/Java on MAC

Tags: java, postgresql, pljava

I’m really having trouble installing Pl/Java on Mac, any help would be appreciated.

I’ll describe the exact steps I’ve done in accordance with the [README](http://cvs.pgfoundry.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/pljava/org.postgresql.pljava/docs/readme.html?rev=1.16&content-type=text/html) here, but I still get some errors that I cannot resolve.

(1) I’ve downloaded this version: `pljava-i686-pc-linux-gnu-pg9.0-1.4.2`

(2) I’ve located three files in the directory: `pljava.jar`, `deploy.jar`, `pljava.so`

(3) I’ve put the two *.jars* inside: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib`

(4) I’ve put the *.so* inside: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/data`

(5) I’ve modified the `postgresql.conf` as follows:

```
dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
custom_variable_classes = 'pljava'
pljava.classpath = '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/pljava.jar’
```

(6) I’ve also tried:

```
dynamic_library_path = '$libdir:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/'    (as well as...)
dynamic_library_path = '$libdir:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/data/'
```

(7) I then try to run:

```
Select sqlj.install_jar('/Software/Libraries/test_trigger.jar', 'samples', false);
Select sqlj.set_classpath(‘public’, ‘samples’);
```

Although, I keep getting this error:

```
WARNING:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Method org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Portal._fetch(JZI)I not found

ERROR:  Unable to register native methods

********** Error **********

ERROR: Unable to register native methods
SQL state: XX000
```

Comment: The other issue I have is, the README calls to export: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client.` ... what is the MAC equivalent ?

Comment: Maybe the comments here will help: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.pljava/623

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: You need to build pljava specifically for Mac. You can't use the linux one.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue is in not loading the right .jar.  You mentioned in your comments that you were also having a problem with appropriate environment variables specifying where to load modules.  This may in fact be your main issue.  It looks like the equivalent environment variable is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` though you can get more options by looking at `man dyld` and obviously if you are loading the wrong .so or .jar you will get errors like this.